# What is the logic behind holds on kernel packages?

Tags: 16.04, apt, kernel

I am hoping that someone with a bit more knowledge can explain something in regards to doing `apt-get upgrade` in Ubuntu 16.04 and later.

The behavior I am seeing is that `apt-get upgrade` sometimes will not install new kernel packages and sometimes will:

i.e. from the output:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-tools-generic
```

I *do* know that doing a `dist-upgrade` will install those packages (so don't repeat that answer :-).  What I do not know is what is controlling the holds on those packages.
Sometimes new kernels install when doing an `apt-get upgrade` and sometimes the packages are held.

Are these holds being put in by Canonical themselves are are they related to dependencies on other packages?

Answer (score 5):

The `apt-get upgrade` command only upgrades packages to their newer version, it's not going to install a new package or does not remove any to upgrade a package.

When you are upgrading your Kernel, you are actually installing a new Kernel. Ubuntu won't upgrade a kernel, it will install a new one while keeping the old one.

But why? why we install a new version of kernel instead of upgrading it to the last version? the answer is because of stability.

You never know what will happens after a Kernel upgrade, it might fail to boot your system or get your hardware to work correctly. You should always keep the old version so in case of any problem you still have a working machine.

> Never upgrade your working kernel.

Says Slackware [system upgrade guide](http://docs.slackware.com/howtos:slackware_admin:systemupgrade).

---

#### More info

`man apt-get`:

> under no circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or
>              packages not already installed retrieved and installed. New versions of
>              currently installed packages that cannot be upgraded without changing the
>              install status of another package will be left at their current version.

However as you know you can use `apt-get dist-upgrade` or `apt upgrade` to install these "kept back" packages too.

```
$ apt-cache search linux-image-4.4.*-generic | tail -3
linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

see? these are different packages thus a new installation instead of upgrade.

Comment: One thing to note that, Ubuntu's kernel packages are mostly standalone packages and can't be upgraded like other packages. Because the kernel together with version makes the package name

Comment: +1 Yeah as I stated it it will be installed as a new package ;)

Comment: Yeah. I read it. But even if it wouldn't, you can't upgrade a kernel package because an _upgraded_ package is a _new_ package actually. Btw, congrats on reaching the 10k milestone :)

Comment: Thanks ;)  I updated the answer to make it more clear :-)